# Can an empty event slow down Javascript processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have an empty `$(window).resize` function 
I was wondering, would commenting it out have any effect 
on the processing of the page (in speed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did some profiling and yes, calling an empty event function does cause a performance hit, though a very mild one.  Tests done in Chrome.

`1ms` - Trigger click without any event functions bound

`1ms` - Trigger click with 1 empty event function bound

`1ms` - Trigger click with 10 empty event functions bound

`2ms` - Trigger click with 100 empty event functions bound

`11ms` - Trigger click with 1000 empty event functions bound

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the method doesn't do anything, why keep it around?

While the speed increase would be negligible it would still make sense to remove the callback since you're method would still get triggered every time the page is resized. So yes, go ahead and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

**Measurably: probably not.**

Commenting out the handler results in the function not being bound to the resize event, thus resulting in a lower memory footprint; the code still has to be downloaded to the client, so bandwidth-wise, you would gain nothing (as a matter of fact, commented code results in *more* data being downloaded to the client).

**The main question, however, is: *if you have an empty function in your code, why would you keep it there?***

Comment: when the function itself is not commented out - only its content, I remember better to put something inside it in the future... it's a personal thing i guess

Comment: @Asaf I see. Well, the speed loss would still be hardly measurable, so if that is your primary worry, you can go ahead and leave it.